# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SoundRecognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm

I want to install SoundRecongnition package but I'm getting the following error when I type: pip3 install SoundRecognition

"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SoundRecognition (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for SoundRecognition"

I tried upgrading the pip. Also tried using the --user tag but still facing the problem.
I'm using pip 19.0.3 version, python 3.7.0 version, and Pycharm as IDE.

Comment: Have you tried installing it via pycharm?

Comment: I tried but couldn't find any package named "soundrecognition" in pycharm's search field.

Answer (score 6):

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement speech_recognition (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for speech_recognition

just use

```py
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no [SoundRecongnition](https://pypi.org/project/SoundRecongnition/) at PyPI (it is where from `pip` installs packages). What package do you mean? I cannot find it on the Net.

Do you mean [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)?

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake. The package name is SpeechRecognition. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 pip install SpeechRecognition
```

you just try above SpeechRecognition...i think sound recognition module not there in pip